# C Programming: Getting a line of text from a specific number

Tags: c

Just need to know how to go about this program:

User enters a number (x)
Program opens text file and reads the xth line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just try to write code for reading the file line by line.  Chances are that you'll figure the rest.

Comment: use `getline()` to read entire and increment counter until you reach `x`th line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int end = 1, bytes = 512, loop = 0, line = 0;
    char *str = NULL;
    FILE *fd = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Enter the line number to read : ");
    scanf("%d", &line);

    do {
        getline(&str, &bytes, fd);
        loop++;
        if (loop == line)
            end = 0;
    }while(end);

    printf("\nLine-%d: %s\n", line, str);
    fclose(fd);
}
```

Read the line from file using `getline` and make the line count. When line count meet desired line stop reading.

Further details [man getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)

Comment: Undefined reference to getline()

Comment: @user3227362 What was your `OS` and `C` compiler

Comment: I am not much know about dev c++. `getline` function available in `libc`. above code will work under linux with gcc. Install `cygwin` in windows and try to run the code with gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to write code. This is something you can use to start

For C++

```
std::string line;
ifstream file("file.txt");
for(int i = 0; i < desired_line; ++i)
   getline(file, line);
```

For C

```
cin>>line;
int ch, lines = 0;
while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
if (ch == '\n') {
    lines++;
    if (lines == line - 1)
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: tag is in `c` not `c++`

Comment: oops my bad. I have edited it.